# Coproduct of Algebras with unary operation

Tags: category-theory

What is the coproduct of $C:=(\{0,1,2\}, f_1)$ and $D:=(\{e,a,b\},f_2)$, where $f_1: 0 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 0$ and $f_2: e \rightarrow b \rightarrow a \rightarrow e$ are unary operations? I’m having a hard time with this.

Is it enough to use $\{0,1,2\} \cup \{e,a,b\}$? But how should I define the operation and the homomorphism?

Comment: What do you mean by type (1)?

Comment: There is only an unary operation defined on these algebras, $f_1$ and $f_2$

Comment: The operation you want on $\{0,1,2,e,a,b\}$ agrees with $f_1$ on $\{0,1,2\}$ and with $f_2$ on $\{e,a,b\}$.

Comment: If I've gotten my calculations correct, the underlying set functor from sets-with-unary-operations to sets has a right adjoint which sends $A \mapsto A^{\mathbb{N}}$ with unary operation $f \mapsto (n \mapsto f(n+1))$.  That would imply that the underlying set functor respects coproducts.